# How to make a generic enum which could hold a Class<T>?

Tags: java, generics, enums

Suppose I have a signature

```
<T>IInterface<T> method(Class<T> myClass)
```

Is it possible to write enum which could hold a class type to be able to pass the instance to method?

```
method(MyEnum.STEP)
```

And STEP is a class.

Actually I want to change the signature of method to pass not `Class<T> myClass` but enum. But I don't want to modify return value type `<T>IInterface<T>`.

```
<T>IInterface<T> method(MyEnum type)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of an enum constant is always an object which is an instance of the enum class. You cannot make it have a different value; neither a reference to a class, nor anything else.

You can add instance fields on your enum which can hold whatever values you want for each enum constant:

```
enum MyEnum {
    STEP(Step.class),
    FOO(Foo.class),
    BAR(Bar.class);

    public final Class<?> klass;

    private MyEnum(Class<?> klass) {
        this.klass = klass;
    }
}
```

(using the variable name `klass` because `class` is a reserved keyword).

You can invoke this with:

```
method(MyEnum.STEP.klass);
```

However, it doesn't preserve the generic type information. The `klass` field is of type `Class<?>` for every enum constant, so the return type of `method(MyEnum.STEP.klass)` will be `IInterface<?>` and not `IInterface<Step>`.

Enums *cannot be generic*, and so their fields cannot have different types for different constants. If you need to preserve the generic type information in the constant you will have to abandon the use of an enum for this purpose and fake it with a class instead. Then you can declare each constant with a different type:

```
class MyConstant<T> {
    public static final MyConstant<Step> STEP = new MyConstant<>();
    public static final MyConstant<Foo> FOO = new MyConstant<>();
    public static final MyConstant<Bar> BAR = new MyConstant<>();

    private MyConstant() {}
}
```

This will give you almost exactly the method signature you wanted:

```
<T> IInterface<T> method(MyConstant<T> type)
```

which is invoked as:

```
IInterface<Step> something = method(MyConstant.STEP);
```

If you also need the type information available at run time, you can add the class value as a field on the constants, in the same way as with the enum example:

```
class MyConstant<T> {
    public static final MyConstant<Step> STEP = new MyConstant<>(Step.class);
    public static final MyConstant<Foo> FOO = new MyConstant<>(Foo.class);
    public static final MyConstant<Bar> BAR = new MyConstant<>(Bar.class);

    public final Class<T> klass;

    private MyConstant(Class<T> klass) {
        this.klass = klass;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does't work. Required: `IInterface<T>` but found: `IInterface<?>`

Comment: @barbara You're right, I overlooked the fact that you needed to use the enum constant to infer the return type of the method. I've edited my answer now.